# How Should we construct compost pit which doesn't produce odour or breeding ground for mosquito or termite

Tags: concrete, smell, termite, mosquitoes

I'd like to construct a compost pit near my house which will collect dried tea bags, fruit & vegetable wastes or unwanted food left overs.

I believe over the time , it'll degrade and start becoming the manure or bio fertiliser and I can use it for my garden.

I initially thought I can build a concrete pit and have a concrete cap this way I can avoid the unwanted odour or mosquitos or termites.

But I wonder if that can stop bio degradation ,I'd like to try proven methods , install of shooting in the dark.

Comment: This really isn't home improvement.  Try the gardening site. Also, Google  "How to construct a compost pit". There are many videos.

Comment: Proper composting requires quite a bit of material all at once. I want to say "at least 1 cubic yard." The mass insulates it so heat kills seeds and pathogens. It sounds like you might only have enough mass for a rotting rubbish pile. Have you considered vermicompost, i.e. worms? Younger kids love it, if you've got kids.

Comment: @popham -It'd be great to do vermicompost as well but how do we go about doing it without of the problems I mentioned above ?

Comment: @JACK - I'm confused whether closing the pit would stop the waste from becoming the bio-fertiliser ? I mean manure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build composter from plastic and steal barrel.

Made a Door, and few pipe vents.

Barrels you can get at recicling centers cheep.

Than build a frame and mounted the barrel so I can rotate it from time to time (mixing)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't hold a pool of standing water, it won't be a breeding ground for mosquitos. And a compost pile shouldn't do so.

Termites want solid wood to tunnel into. Nothing that goes into a compost pile should be large enough to host a termite colony. And termites are perfectly fine critters as long as they aren't eating wood you want to preserve.

A compost pile doesn't stink unless you throw things into it that should not be composted, like meat and fats.

There are lots of websites that answer all these questions and provide detailed designs and recommendations. I'd suggest you do a bit of homework on the topic and come back here -- or, better, to the gardening stack -- if there is something specific that you are confused about.

Comment: If I close the pit with a lid , all the problems would get resolved but whether the waste would bio-degrade and become the compost or vermicompost that's my confusion really